# Yarn doesn't install the dependencies on node_modules folder

Tags: reactjs, yarnpkg

I'm trying to create a react app using `yarn create react-app` but the dependencies are being installed on .yarn folder. Do you know how can I fix that and install the dependencies on node_modules folder?

Answer (score 0):

**You are going to want to use `yarn create react-app appname`**

An alternative would be `npx create-react-app appname`, but the command you mentioned won't do what you are trying to accomplish.

Then to **install the dependencies** enter the directory you just created by using `cd appname` and then `yarn install`.

Comment: You're right, the command is `yarn create react-app`. I've updated the post

Comment: Perfect. Just make sure you are in the same directory as `package.json` and you should be able to install dependencies properly with `yarn install`

Comment: Still not working.

Comment: if you type `ls` does it list `package.json`?

Answer (score 0):

A bit late, but if anyone is looking for the same problem, it's because the new versions of Yarn are using Plug'n'Play witch doesn't use node_modules anymore, beeing much faster than when using node_modules. You can find all the informations on [their website](https://yarnpkg.com/features/pnp)

And if you still want to use the old way,and disable PnP, you can add in your **.yarnrc.yml** file the following: `nodeLinker: node-modules` and rerun a `yarn install`